# How do I implement a database in Android?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I need a database for my quiz-like app to store questions and their related information. Due to the extensive nature of the information I need to store, an SQLite database seems to be the only reasonable solution.

I have done some PHP and thus am familiar with MySQL. But the main difference, and the biggest source of confusion, is that there is no way to manage the SQLite database in Android except for java code and I'm not sure how to deal with this logistically the best way. I just need to insert questions once and after that I won't write anything to the database, just read.

Do I write the code with the insert statements, run the app to make it add to the database and then just delete the code, rinse, repeat? It seems like such a cumbersome way, but I can't see any other way.

Comment: Maybe you are not aware of a nice FireFox plugin called SQLite Manager... https://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/

Comment: I know such comments are not liked a lot, but: Did you read the documentation on developer.android.com (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)? They do have samples, you know?

Comment: I think the OP wants something to VISUALLY work out a database before starting to use it in code.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I already know how to do the coding part. It just seems like a weird process to write all that code and do it over and over again just to insert to the database, when all I basically want is a table with some text in it.  Of course I read the documentation, but I couldn't find an answer, and still can't in there, so that's why I asked. 

How are cases like mine usually handled (Only read from DB)? SQLite Manager seems to be exactly what I'm looking for but I've never seen it mentioned with Android before, so I'm thinking maybe it's not good practice or something?